# Not able to transfer my ETH from the Smart Contract to an User Account while using Truffle or ReactJS with Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, metamask, react

My below `Solidity` code is working fine in the `RemixIDE`, where the code objective is to take some donated ETH from any Etherium account and transfer all the collected ETH to the contract owner address.

Now the problem comes when I'm trying to trigger the `transferEth()` function from the Truffle or from core React code with the support of Web3JS+Ganache. I'm getting no error in the console and neither the `transferEth()` function is working.

> EthTransfer.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity 0.8.12;

contract EthTransfer{
    address public sender;
    address public receiver;

    constructor(){
        receiver = msg.sender;
    }

    receive() external payable{
        sender = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function getContractBalance() public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getContractAddress() public view returns(address){
        return address(this);
    }

    function transferEth() public {
        payable(receiver).transfer(getContractBalance());
    }
}
```

> Truffles React Component (POC.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import EthTransfer from "./contracts/EthTransfer.json";
import getWeb3 from "./getWeb3";
import "./App.css";

class POC extends Component{

    state = { web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null };

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        try {
            // Get network provider and web3 instance.
            const web3 = await getWeb3();

            // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
            const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

            // Get the contract instance.
            const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();

            const deployedNetwork = EthTransfer.networks[networkId];

            const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
                EthTransfer.abi,
                deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
              );

            this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance });
    
        } catch (error) {
          // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
          alert(
            `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
          );
          console.error(error);
        }
      };

      getContractAddress = async () => {
        const { contract } = this.state;
        const getTheContractAddress = await contract.methods.getContractAddress().call();
        console.log('Contract Address: '+getTheContractAddress);
      };

      getContractBalance = async () => {
        const { contract } = this.state;
        let getTheContractBalance  = await contract.methods.getContractBalance().call();
        console.log('Contract Balance at '+Date().toLocaleString()+': '+getTheContractBalance);
      };

      transferEtherium = async () => {
        const { web3, accounts, contract } = this.state;
        await contract.methods.transferEth().call().then(response => {
          console.log('`transferEtherium` is executed.!');
        }
        ).catch(e => {
          console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
        });  
      };

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Good to Go!</h1>
            <p>Ready to test POC.</p>
            <button onClick={this.getContractAddress}>getContractAddress</button>
            <button onClick={this.getContractBalance}>getContractBalance</button>
            <button onClick={this.transferEtherium}>transferEtherium</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
}

export default POC;
```

[image: Here is the execution flow, I've transferred 1.5ETH to the smart contract and triggered the transferEth() function but nothing happens for me. The contract still holding the 1.5ETH and no error has occured]

Here is the execution flow, I've transferred 1.5ETH to the smart contract and triggered the `transferEth()` function but nothing happens for me. The contract still holding the 1.5ETH and no error has occured

Comment: change the `.call`  in `await contract.methods.transferEth().call().then(response => {...})` to a `.send`, call will not alter the state, while send will as it will be made through a public transaction.

Comment: Did the suggested changes but getting, `Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.` in the console. My smart contract knows, from which account the ETH needs to be transferred to which account. Is there any way to its core functionality?

Comment: Yes, because to send a public transaction you must have an on chain identity associated with it. Try to follow the example (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.1/web3-eth-contract.html#id37) where you specify the `from` parameter with the address of your current account.